# On Joining TObjectlists

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010, concatenation, tobjectlist

I think i need a nudge in the right direction:

I have two Tobjectlists of the same datatype, and i want to concatenate these into a new list into which list1 shall be copied (unmodified) followed by list2 (in reverse)

```
type
  TMyListType = TobjectList<MyClass>

var
  list1, list2, resList : TMyListtype

begin
  FillListWithObjects(list1);
  FillListWithOtherObjects(list2);

  list2.reverse

  //Now, I tried to use resList.Assign(list1, list2, laOr), 
  //but Tobjectlist has no Assign-Method. I would rather not want to 
  //iterate over all objects in my lists to fill the resList
end;
```

Does delphi have any built-in function to merge two Tobjectlists into one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `TObjectList.AddRange()` and set `OwnsObjects` to `False` to avoid double-freeing of the items in `LRes`.

```
var
  L1, L2, LRes: TObjectList<TPerson>;
  Item: TPerson;

{...}

L1 := TObjectList<TPerson>.Create();
try
  L2 := TObjectList<TPerson>.Create();
  try

    LRes := TObjectList<TPerson>.Create();
    try
      L1.Add(TPerson.Create('aa', 'AA'));
      L1.Add(TPerson.Create('bb', 'BB'));

      L2.Add(TPerson.Create('xx', 'XX'));
      L2.Add(TPerson.Create('yy', 'YY'));

      L2.Reverse;

      LRes.OwnsObjects := False;
      LRes.AddRange(L1);
      LRes.AddRange(L2);

      for Item in LRes do
      begin
        OutputWriteLine(Item.FirstName + ' ' + Item.LastName);
      end;

    finally
      LRes.Free;
    end;

  finally
    L2.Free;
  end;

finally
  L1.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Note that AddRange is available only on the generic version of TObjectList, so it did not exist in 2006 (and probably 2007). Should be ok if you use a recent version. Otherwise you have to make this add-all loop. It is simple enough...

Comment: Well, the OP's using a generic TObjectList in his example, so he should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the answer supplied looks like it only works in XE.. in 2010 (and presumably below) the AddRange function does not have an overload that takes a TObjectList as its parameter (compiling the above code snippet gives an E2250 on the AddRange lines).

Currently spending a day working if generics will help simplify code in a large project but the lack of an assign function (or any usable equivalent) is a showstopper.  Seems odd to release something in D2009 then require 2 major releases before it actually works!